# How to render a component and have accses to the values inside that component from parent component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I come across this situation quite often where I need to build the component in standalone and I also need to access the states or functions declared inside that component from a parent component. For example,

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Zoom level :{zoomLvl}</p>
      <ChildComponent />;<button onClick={handleZoom}>Zoom In</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const ChildComponent = () => {
  const [zoomLvl, setZoomLvl] = useState(0);

  const handleZoom = () => {
    setZoomLvl(2);
  };
  return <SomeJSX>...</SomeJSX>;
};
```

In this case, I don't want to move these states and functions `[zoomLvl,setZoomLvl] , handleZoom` into the parent component for reusablility, but I need to have access to them from `ParentComponent`. What is the easiest, simplest ant cleanest solution to achieve this?

Comment: You will need to pull state up somehow. Either to the parent component, or a context.

Comment: you can use `useImperativeHandle` hook. For ex - see https://codesandbox.io/s/useimperativehandle-cgxo9?file=/src/index.js